# Lightbox Video not centering on Wordpress

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, overlay, lightbox

not sure how to fix this 
http://www.eastangliaultrasound.co.uk/test/

when clicking on green banner (says "Harmony") video should be vertically centered, anyone knows how to fix this?

```
element.style {
display: block;
z-index: 9999;
top: 111.5px;
position: fixed;
}

.lightbox_ultimate_fp_overlay {
display: none;
padding: 15px;
width: 640px;
background-color: #fff;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Do you use a plugin or something?

It seems that inline style is added on `<div class="lightbox_ultimate_fp_overlay">`. In my browser, the `top` value isn't `111.5px` but `95.9px;`. That means your plugin/jQuery stuff calculate himself the position.

Do you have some options somewhere to change this? If not, you can modify the plugin but it's not recommended :/

Comment: i cannot change it anywhere unless i modify plugin - dont wanna do that

Comment: Yep don't do that. Because the position is calculated automatically, **except adding a script that passes over the plugin**, I do not know how to help you better. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

not sure of your exact config - but you could try adding this to your child theme's css :

```
.lightbox_ultimate_fp_overlay{
   left:23%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Manoz already said, the plugin calculate the windows size and the position for the video. For the vertical centering you could use:

```
.lightbox_ultimate_fp_overlay {
    width: 50% !important;
    left: 25%;
}
```